# Import less-stylesheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, asset-pipeline

I want to update our design.
The design was made using .less Stylesheets.

But I can't import the file.

`File to import not found or unreadable: frontend/style.
 Load paths:
 /srv/app_name/app/assets/fonts
 /srv/app_name/app/assets/images
 /srv/app_name/app/assets/javascripts
 /srv/app_name/app/assets/stylesheets`

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'  
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.7.0'  
...  
gem 'execjs'  
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.frontend.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";  
@import "bootstrap";  
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";  
@import "font-awesome";  
...  
@import "frontend/style";
```

The Stylesheet is in **app/assets/stylesheets/frontend/style.css.less**
I also tried *.less

Comment: The `scss/sass` preprocessor cannot import `less` stylesheets. You could try converting it to `scss/sass` via https://github.com/brauliobo/less2sass, but I doubt that will be a straightforward conversion.

Comment: What @AaronBreckenridge said; you'll need to use a gem to compile your less or some preprocessor like Codekit or gulp